# Can I buy DLC for Games I do not own the Steam Version of?

Tags: steam, rome-total-war

If I have a normal version of a game (in this case Rome : Total War/ Rome : Total War Barbarian Invasion) and I want a DLC (Rome : Total War Alexander) from Steam, will it work with my other games that are not from Steam?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I buy DLC for a game I don't have installed?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124075/can-i-buy-dlc-for-a-game-i-dont-have-installed)

Comment: @Frank: That says which you do own, but haven't installed. This is asking about if you don't even own it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot purchase DLC on Steam when you do not own the Steam version of the Game. For some older Games Steam does accept the CD Key to unlock this Game on Steam though.

See this list: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601

This is not the case for the original version of Total War : Rome though. Only Rome II will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the DLC won't work with the normal version. [This Steam forum thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1627360) and [also this one](http://steamcommunity.com/app/48240/discussions/0/864961721862028296/) suggest that it is not possible to buy DLC for non-Steam games. There are a number of retail games that don't require steam, but can be registered and added to your account with codes that can be found [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601).

Unfortunately, Rome: Total War is not on that list and it doesn't seem to be enough to just add it as a non-Steam game into your Steam library to download DLC for it.

Comment: and do you know any other way that i could get the DLC through the internet?, because I live in a small town and we don't have very big gaming store...

Comment: the add-on Alexander has been released as a retail version in some areas. I remember back in the day when it came out, it was announced as an online-only add-on, but soon after I saw it lying in stores in Germany, and I've found a retail verison on the German and UK amazon. Depending on where you live, you could try buying it there and have it sent to you: www.amazon.co.uk/Rome-Total-War-Alexander-Expansion/dp/B000NJZSPU/

I don't think there is another way to get it throuhg the internet.

Comment: Seems like there is another way:

http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-ROMETWALX/rome-total-war-alexander

I'm not sure though if it still needs Steam, but it doesn't look like it, since it doesn't say it in the description and lists SecuRom as copy protection.

Answer (score 1):

No. The [Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/4770/) clearly states (emphasis mine):

> Notice: The Rome: Total War Alexander Expansion requires the **Steam version** of Rome: Total War Gold to purchase.

If you add it to your cart, and try to purchase it, you will receive the following message:

> Your transaction failed because you are trying to buy 'Rome: Total War™ - Alexander ' which requires ownership of 'Rome: Total War™'. Please correct the error and try again.